# imagejpeg não está salvando imagem

Tags: php

Segue o código, depois a pergunta.

```
$localDiretorioFoto = "img/mensagens/";
$img = $_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];
$imgg = getimagesize($img);

if($imgg["mime"] == "image/jpeg") {
    $nomeFoto = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
} else if($imgg["mime"] == "image/png") {
    $nomeFoto = imagecreatefrompng($img);
}

imagejpeg($nomeFoto, $localDiretorioFoto, 50);
```

Estou tentando salvar uma imagem, e estou salvando o $nomeFoto no bd, porém o que ele salva é: *Resource id #4* e a imagem não é salva na pasta *img/mensagens/* por que?

Devo usar header e/ou imagedestroy? Se sim, por que?

Comment: Alguém? :(.....

Comment: Estou tentando criar uma resposta. =)

Comment: Ah, okay @Qmechanic73! Obrigado.

Comment: Arrisquei uma resposta, veja se é isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) e derivadas retornam o recurso identificador da imagem se tiverem sucesso, o *Resource id #4* indica que você está manipulando um recurso.

A imagem não está sendo salva porque você está especificando somente o diretório, o nome da imagem é omitido.

Você pode estar fazendo algo parecido com isto:

```
if (isset($_FILES['foto'])){
    $path = $_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];
    $nomeFoto = $_FILES["foto"]["name"];
    $diretorioFoto = "img/mensagens/". $nomeFoto;
    $imageSize = getimagesize($path);

    switch(strtolower($imageSize['mime'])){
        case 'image/jpeg':
          $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
          break;
        case 'image/png':
          $img = imagecreatefrompng($path);
          break;
        default: die();
    }

    if(imagejpeg($img, $diretorioFoto, 50) === true){
        echo "Imagem salva em ". $diretorioFoto;
    } else {
        echo "Erro ao salvar a imagem em ". $diretorioFoto;
    }
}
```

A função [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) não é necessária nesse caso pois você quer salvar a imagem somente. O [`imagedestroy`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagedestroy.php) é utilizado para liberar a memória associada a um objeto. Nesse caso poderíamos utilizá-lo assim:

```
imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: Obrigado por se disponibilizar a ajudar. Testei e continua da mesma maneira, Resource id #4 e não cria nada na pasta img/men...

Comment: @Igor Bah, atualizei a resposta, testei aqui e funcionou veja se contigo funciona também.

Comment: Agora sim funcionou! Muito obrigado @Qmechanic73!!!!!